# Из-за js перестаёт работать кнопка

Tags: javascript, html

Есть [js файл](https://nloshop.com.ua/js/confirm.js) без него перестаёт нажиматься кнопка "Оформить заказ" и при нажатии ничего не происходит, если подключу обратно то будет работать всё отлично но вот тогда другие начинают отваливаться и не работать.

Кнопка:

```html
<button style="margin-top:15px;" type="submit" name="submitdata" id="confirm-button-next" name="button" type="submit" class="step__footer__continue-btn btn">
  <span class="btn__content">Оформить заказ</span>
  <i class="btn__spinner icon icon--button-spinner"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы подключаете foundation. Возможно, у вас происходит конфликт скриптов. Попробуйте одно из следующих решений:

1) Подключить ваш файл самым последним, после всех остальных скриптов

2) Найти кусок кода в файле, который отвечает только за функционал вашей кнопки, скопировать его и вставить отдельно, или же к уже имеющемуся файлу скриптов.